# Understand a C program

Tags: c

```
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
     }
     s[i] = '\0';

     return i;
 }
```

In the above function, how does the `s[]` work as the `getchar()` function gets one character at time even when you input a whole line to it.

e.g. my first line of input is "hello" and it is six characters long including the null character at the end.

In for loop in first cycle i is 1, then how is `s[1] = c` puts the line hello in `s[1]` as hello is 6 characters long and `s[1]` is only one character?

Comment: First, based on how you tagged your question, understand that C and C++ are two different languages...

Comment: Start with a basic C book or tutorials. `char s[]` is nothing rare.

Comment: You need to re-write this question _then how can the second array element `s[1] = c`_  because it's not clear. And this functions is just emulating `fgets()` for `stdin`. i.e. `fgets(array, sizeof(array), stdin);` is equivalent to `getline(array, sizeof(array));`.

Comment: Why are you saying that in the first cycle `i == 1`? don't you see that it's `0`?

Comment: Doesn't ++i increment i at the end of the for statement?

Comment: Yes but that will be evaluated after the first iteration, not before.

Comment: @RajS: The `++i` is executed after the body of the loop, before the loop condition is tested again.

Comment: Okay, then how will s[0] = c contain hello if my first line of input is hello?

Comment: No, it will contain `h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the code does is fetch one character from the input stream at a time, and then store the character at the `i`th position in the `s` array, then it increments `i`.

It tests for two conditions, if `i == lim - 1` then the loop ends, and the `'\0'` is appended at the `lim` position in the array, if a `'\n'` was encounterd or the `EOF` end of file was reached, then the loop also ends.

In case the last character read was `'\n'` then it's appended at the `i`th position, and `i` is incremented, and then a `'\0'` is appended at new `i`th position.

If not, then just append `'\0'` at the `i`th position, and return.

No character will be read until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, so the loop will actually start running after the moment <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, and the algorithm will do what I describe.

Comment: If the inputs are 

hello
how
are
you

What will this function return?

Comment: It will depend on the `lim` value.

Comment: In that case the ouput will be `hello how are you\n\0` and some uninitialized bytes after that, of course, if the `s` array is big enough.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you type several characters and hit Enter the getchar() would return one character at a time for each invocation.

So for the first iteration, `i=0` and `c='h'` --> `s[0]='h'`. On the second iteration `s[1]='e'`, on the third `s[2]='l'`, etc.

Comment: If the inputs are 

hello
how
are
you

What will this function return?